# Implicit xaml style overwritten by explicit style

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I Have this very simple xaml style problem in Silverlight4.

When I set a style on element through explicit styling my implicit style is removed?
I created a simple example to illustrate the problem.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="red"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="test">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20"/>
    </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource test}" Height="40" Width="120"> </TextBox>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So when I remove the `Style="{StaticResource test}`
the implicit style is applied again.

Note: this is oversimplified example. So moving the margin to the texbox style is not an option because the real project contains larger xaml styling.

Does somebody know a solution or can confirm that this isn't possible?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the BasedOn style property.  This will allow you to inherit from a base style, to use the base properties and add some changes.

Now, there is a problem with BasedOn - it can't be used with an implicit style.  However, this is pretty easy to work around.  This article demonstrates the work around and will also explain the BasedOn property a bit better:

[Silverlight how-to: Inherit from an Implicit Style](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2010/09/05/silverlight-how-to-inherit-from-an-implicit-style.aspx)

Comment: Hey, thx for the response I know how to use the basedon but it's not very usefull in this context because you can't base a framework style on a textbox one. In the final code the texbox will include a custom template...

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want to base the TextBox style on the FrameworkElement style?

Comment: No because because I want to add styling to textbox in some cases. It maybe not very clear because I oversimplified the above example the final one is more complex and needs the proper order.